# File system access exception in hadoop map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have configured the Hadoop 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. I am running wordcount map reduce program initially to get know about the map reduce jobs. I am facing some issue while accessing the file system. I am having the Hadoop home directory in `/opt/hadoop2.6.0`.

1. Driver program

   ```
       Configuration conf = new Configuration();
       Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
       job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
       job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
       job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
       job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
       job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
       job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
       // configuration should contain reference to your namenode
        FileSystem hdfs =FileSystem.get(new Configuration()); 
       Path workingDir=hdfs.getWorkingDirectory();

       Path newFolderPath= new Path("/output");

       newFolderPath=Path.mergePaths(workingDir, newFolderPath);

       if(hdfs.exists(newFolderPath))

       {

           hdfs.delete(newFolderPath, true); //Delete existing Directory

       }
       hdfs.mkdirs(newFolderPath); 
       FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
       FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,newFolderPath );
       System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1); //line no. 76
       // job.submit();
   ```
2. core-site.xml

   ```
   <configuration>
       <property>
           <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
           <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> 
           <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value> 
       </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. hdfs-site.xml

   ```
   <configuration>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.replication</name>
           <value>1</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
           <value>/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/dfs/name</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
           <value>/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/dfs/data</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
           <value>false</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.http.address</name>
           <value>localhost:50070</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
           <value>true</value>
       </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
4. yarn-site.xml

   ```
   <configuration>

     <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties --> <property>
           <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>  
           <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value> </property> <property>      
           <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>   
             <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value> </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
            <value>
                 %HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop,
                 %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\common\*,
                 %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\common\lib\*,
                 %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs\*,
                 %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*,
                 %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*,
                 %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*,
                 %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\yarn\*,
                 %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*
            </value> 
       </property>
   ```
5. Running the map reduce jar:

   ```
    hadoop jar /home/ifs-admin/wordcount.jar  WordCount /user/ifs/input
   ```

   **Execution Exception:**

   ```
       15/08/23 12:12:25 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
       15/08/23 12:12:25 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
       Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory
       hdfs://localhost:9000/user/ifs-admin/output already exists
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:562)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
       at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:76)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
   ```
6. If I delete the output directory, it shows me following error:

   ```
      Exception in thread "main" ENOENT: No such file or directory
       at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
       at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:230)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:652)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:490)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:599)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:182)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
       at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:68)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
   ```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this code
Note- do not create directory , hadoop will do automatically

```
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://localhost:9000"),
            conf); 
    Path workingDir=hdfs.getWorkingDirectory();

    Path newFolderPath= new Path("/output");
    newFolderPath=Path.mergePaths(workingDir, newFolderPath);
    if(hdfs.exists(newFolderPath))

    {
        hdfs.delete(newFolderPath); //Delete existing Directory

    }
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,newFolderPath );
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1); //line no. 76
    // job.submit();
```

Comment: Hi Krish, this gives me an exception: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/ifs-admin/output already exists. Is there any configuration issue?

Comment: In windows it works well. Is there any permision issue in Ubuntu? I have tried chown -R and changed the directory to /usr/local/hadoop. Please help

Comment: have you remove this code from program---hdfs.mkdirs(newFolderPath);

Comment: given code is working fine on linux. try with other directory

Comment: hadoop is not able to create the directory. It is showing error, Exception in thread "main" ENOENT: No such file or directory. If, I create the directory using -mkdir -p. It is showing exception, Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/ifs-admin/output already exists. I am struck down. Any help, May I know your single node setup?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is not able to create the directory in hdfs while we set the temp.dir or name node dir or data node dir under /opt folder.
visit : 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/what-is-the-difference-between-opt-and-usr-local.

I have change the hadoop.tmp.dir in core-site.xml to /usr/local/hadoop/dfs/data.